# AngularJS - single alert div for multiple controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have a single bootstrap 3 alert to show general error or success messages for all the operations a user can perform on a page. The page is divided in different sections with different controllers per section, something like this:

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="securityController">
    [controller methods for change password, validate user section, ...]
    <div ng-controller="salesController"> 
      <div class="alert" ng-show="message.visible"><strong>{{message.title}}</strong>{{message.text}}</div></div>
      [controller methods for admin sales, admin products, admin retails, ...]
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Then I want to be able to bind this html to all the models in the controllers who want to show a message when a user performs an action in the page (Ej. security messages when it interacts with securityController methods, validation messages when it interacts with salesController methods)

First I thought that cascading the controllers and making them have models with the name of the binding variables used in the alert HTML could work (Ej. having a $scope.message object in securityController and in salesController) but it didn't work and I don't really think that is the correct approach.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample code which I had written for one of my app.

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/pGhKOTtqFxpD4fukhQrl?p=preview

**Directive:**

```
app.directive('alert', function(alertService) {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    link: function(scope, e, a, ctl) {
      scope.alert = alertService.alertObj;
    },
    template: '<div class="alert" ng-class="alert.type" ng-show="alert.show">{{alert.msg}}</div>'
  };
});
```

**Service:** Links multiple controllers with the directive.

```
app.service('alertService', function() {
  var me = this;
  me.alertObj = {
    show: false,
    msg: '',
    type: 'alert-success'
  };
  me.alertShow = false;
  me.alertTypes = ['alert-success', 'alert-info', 'alert-warning', 'alert-danger'];
  me.alert = function(type, msg) {
    me.alertObj.msg = msg;
    me.alertObj.type = me.alertTypes[type];
    me.alertObj.show = true;
  };
  me.success = function(msg) {
    me.alert(0, msg);
  };
  me.info = function(msg) {
    me.alert(1, msg);
  };
  me.warning = function(msg) {
    me.alert(2, msg);
  };
  me.danger = function(msg) {
    me.alert(3, msg);
  };
  me.hide = function() {
    console.log('hiding');
    me.alertObj.show = false;
  };
  return this;
});
```

**controller:** Sample controller

```
app.controller('ctl1', function($scope, alertService) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.showAlert = function() {
    alertService.success("This is an success alert");
  };
});
```

HTML:

```
<alert></alert>
  <div ng-controller="ctl1">
    <button ng-click="showAlert()">ctl1 - Success alert</button>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="ctl2">
    <button ng-click="showAlert()">ctl2 - Warning alert</button>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="ctl3">
    <button ng-click="showAlert()">ctl3 - Danger alert</button>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="ctl4">
    <button ng-click="showAlert()">ctl4 - Info alert</button>
    <button ng-click="hide()">Clear Alert</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Wow! I didn't know you could initialize directives with services and then use service objects in the template! This is my chosen answer.

Answer (score 2):

Something similar I wanted to do with Bootstrap's modal, to be able to display it to user when any error occurs.

First a Service:

```
.service('ErrorService', function() {
    var error;

    this.setError = function(value) {
        error = value;
    };

    this.getError = function() {
        return error;
    };

    this.clearError = function() {
        error = undefined;
    };
})
```

Then a directive which looks on the service's `getError` and displays itself if the service returns some value:

```
.directive('errorModal', ['ErrorService', 
    function(ErrorService) {
        return {
            link: function($scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller) {
                $scope.$watch(ErrorService.getError, function(newVal, oldVal) {
                    if (newVal) {
                        // service returned something, display this modal foe further!
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

If you want to set the error, from any controller any other JS code (where you have injected the service of course!) just do:

```
ErrorService.setError(someError);
```

And the directive I have included only once in the HTML code in index.html:

```
<div error-modal></div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: In the $scope.$watch part of the directive, shouldn't it be ErrorService.setError instead of ErrorService.getError?

Comment: No. The `getError` returns the value and in the `$scope.$watch` we want to know (to watch) what the service returns (what it was set to earlier, from some other part of the app).

Comment: I forgot to mention the `clearError`, that is called after a Close button in the directive is clicked

Comment: Thanks! your answer and @guru's answer are the right approach but I chose guru's since its answer addresses my exact use case(bootstrap alerts).