# AngularJS: How to share scope functions and variables with other controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I've multiple controllers in my application, where I have some duplicate code like:

```
$scope.alert = null;

$scope.addAlert = function (message) {
    $scope.alert = { type: 'danger', msg: message };
};

$scope.clearAlerts = function () {
    $scope.alert = null;
};
```

What is the recommended way sharing these scope functions and variables in AngularJS? Using controller inheritance?

Comment: Using services https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Comment: possible duplicate of [Global variables in AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938380/global-variables-in-angularjs)

Comment: Controller inheritance is not a good practice. Use `factory` and `service` for that

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS - single alert div for multiple controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24075447/angularjs-single-alert-div-for-multiple-controllers)

Comment: @RobsonGilli But if I use a service, then the alert variable in the service will be shared between all controllers using it. Right? I need each controller to have its own `alert`.

Comment: In my case I created an alert service that receives from the controllers the type, title and message, and presents the alert to the user based on that information. the answer from @pankajparkar seems to be the way to go. The service will only be accessible to the controllers you inject the dependency in....

Answer (score 5):

Create a one controller and then place common methods inside that controller scope. So that you can use that scope anywhere else and get access to method inside controller.

**Controller**

```
app.controller('commonCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.alert = null;

    $scope.addAlert = function(message) {
        $scope.alert = {
            type: 'danger',
            msg: message
        };
    };

    $scope.clearAlerts = function() {
        $scope.alert = null;
    };
});
```

Thereafter use scope of this controller by inject it using `$controller`, and then inside curly brace you could assign common controller scope to the current scope of controller.

**Utilization of Common Controller**

```
app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope, $controller) {
    //inject comomon controller scope to current scope , 
    //below line will add 'commonCtrl' scope to current scope
    $controller('commonCtrl', { $scope: $scope }); 
    //common controller scope will be available from here

});
```

Or more precise way would be using common sharable service, that exposed two method and `alert` data, you can use this service method by injecting service name inside your controller.

**Service**

```
app.service('commonService', function($scope) {
    this.alert = null;

    this.addAlert = function(message) {
        this.alert = {
            type: 'danger',
            msg: message
        };
    };

    this.clearAlerts = function() {
        this.alert = null;
    };
});
```

**Utilization of service inside Controller**

```
app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope, commonService) {

  console.log(commonService.alert);
  commonService.addAlert("Something");
  console.log("Updated Alert" + commonService.alert);

});
```

Hope this has cleared your concept, Thanks.

Comment: You should use a service not a controller

Comment: How can I add a service in AngularJS 1.3+? It seems that it's done using a factory, but then all my controllers will share the alert. I need each controller using my service, to have it own instance.

Comment: @DennisMadsen If your requirement is like such, then do create a new controller would be better way (as I mentioned in 1st approach)..rather than creating a service which will initialized new object & give new copy of variable, service/factory does mean that you should use them for shareable purpose

Answer (score 0):

My own solution for this use case was to define a type of Observer Pattern.

The code was structured in the following way:

```
var app = angular.module('testModule', []);
app.factory('alertService', ['$timeout', function($timeout){
    var alertListeners = [];

    this.register = function (listener) {
        alertListeners.push(listener);
    };

    this.notifyAll = function (data) {
    for (// each listener in array) {
        var listenerObject = alertListeners[i];
        try { // do not allow exceptions in individual listeners to corrupt other listener processing
            listenerObject.notify(data);
        } catch(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }   
    }
    };
 }]).
 directive('myAlerts', ['alertService', function(alertService){

     var alertDirectiveObserver = function($scope, alertService) {

        this.notify = function(data) {
        /*
         * TO DO - use data to show alert
         */
         };

         /*
          * Register this object as an event Listener. Possibly supply an event key, and listener id to enable more resuse
          */
         alertService.register(this);

         $scope.on('$destroy', function() {
             alertService.unregister(// some listener id);
         });
     };


   return {
     restrict: 'A',
     template: '<div ng-class="alertClass" ng-show="alertNeeded">{{alertMessage}}</div>',
     controller: ['$scope', 'alertService', alertDirectiveObserver],
     link: function(scope){  
     }
    }
}]).
controller('alertShowingController', ['$scope', 'alertService',   function($scope, alertService){
    alertService.notifyAll({'warning', 'Warning alert!!!'})   
 ]);
```

The `alertShowingController` is a simple example of how all controllers can simply inject the `alertService` and generate an event.

My own implementation is more elaborate in that it uses separate event keys to allow the controllers to generate other event notifications.

I could then define a single div that was in a fixed position at the top of the page that would dispay bootstrap alerts.

```
<div my-alerts ng-repeat="alert in alertList" type="{{alert.type}}" close="closeAlert(alertList, $index)">{{alert.msg}}</div>
```

Comment: In your example it seems that alerts are shared between all controllers, right? I need each controller to have it's own alert.

Comment: I created a plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/BRFAGyeEN29SESVzLPPJ?p=preview, which may help for what you are trying to do